# Decoding polyline in Python

Tags: python, line, google-maps, google-maps-api, polyline-creation

By making Google Maps API call I received a response JSON which contained this polyline:

```
ezdvBcps}Lt@W@F@BVKl@UK]Wc@}@kAOKBEzA{BdA}Ab@s@LBf@RjARZBv@?rAAfBIX?f@FLBf@^b@hATbAF~@BvB?hALjBHpCLjAVdAd@dAxCbGlA~BbBvCpAbD`AnCVpB\\hBf@nB|@tAb@f@RVXLbDj@jCl@nAf@`DbBdC`B`@b@HNN`@lA~DnAvBvB`G\\fA^p@j@z@~E`FbBpBxDfFXh@|@pD`@bB^fANd@\\`Bl@rBb@fATj@v@bBjBwCd@w@NB^B\\@\\K\\Q|AWZGXOPIRBb@K\\Kl@_@VOZWVI^Eh@Ov@KxCJ\\@\\K^@RMh@QhAMXKXY`@Q^SLK`@]fBc@n@M\\OlB_@n@KNMRUZQZGh@Ht@Lx@F`@BTANDRNTPNDDHLXN`@LRTJx@?RBJFFLV\\Zs@TQ`@MVIhAYp@YPc@VgALk@Hk@d@eA\\cAHq@Eo@J}@@q@DItAgAv@i@|@e@v@k@bAaAdDuB|@c@?I?]?{@Ms@COFWJODYEcABOTU^e@H_@Km@Ci@BU?e@Ca@Ie@e@oBKk@Eu@M{@CoAC}@Km@Iy@IaA?{@Ci@Ms@UgA]y@Mm@GQICe@QKMGi@Gi@GSI[Ym@[{@@_AK]SMo@i@OCg@EOEMMYSi@IUO]Ko@KSIWUWMU_@I]Kw@WoACY@a@CWQWe@[QIOYMYW]SMQUQu@OWWSUWU[SsAEg@Ic@Mc@?a@Ai@Em@AUOa@M_@e@g@MSGYOY_@YIQSR[Pa@mBQaAI[@QDyACq@Iu@o@k@e@Y]IcAAmBC]Ee@IgAUWAw@Ae@GWSaAeAYk@Si@a@k@YAc@O{@]a@MnAqA~@mCVaAHk@YmCIQSQOS
```

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility

I wanted to decode it in Python. So, I tried out [`polyline`](https://pypi.org/project/polyline/) package ([github link](https://github.com/frederickjansen/polyline)):

```py
>>> import polyline
>>> l = polyline.decode('ezdvBcps}Lt@W@F@BVKl@UK]Wc@}@kAOKBEzA{BdA}Ab@s@LBf@RjARZBv@?rAAfBIX?f@FLBf@^b@hATbAF~@BvB?hALjBHpCLjAVdAd@dAxCbGlA~BbBvCpAbD`AnCVpB\\hBf@nB|@tAb@f@RVXLbDj@jCl@nAf@`DbBdC`B`@b@HNN`@lA~DnAvBvB`G\\fA^p@j@z@~E`FbBpBxDfFXh@|@pD`@bB^fANd@\\`Bl@rBb@fATj@v@bBjBwCd@w@NB^B\\@\\K\\Q|AWZGXOPIRBb@K\\Kl@_@VOZWVI^Eh@Ov@KxCJ\\@\\K^@RMh@QhAMXKXY`@Q^SLK`@]fBc@n@M\\OlB_@n@KNMRUZQZGh@Ht@Lx@F`@BTANDRNTPNDDHLXN`@LRTJx@?RBJFFLV\\Zs@TQ`@MVIhAYp@YPc@VgALk@Hk@d@eA\\cAHq@Eo@J}@@q@DItAgAv@i@|@e@v@k@bAaAdDuB|@c@?I?]?{@Ms@COFWJODYEcABOTU^e@H_@Km@Ci@BU?e@Ca@Ie@e@oBKk@Eu@M{@CoAC}@Km@Iy@IaA?{@Ci@Ms@UgA]y@Mm@GQICe@QKMGi@Gi@GSI[Ym@[{@@_AK]SMo@i@OCg@EOEMMYSi@IUO]Ko@KSIWUWMU_@I]Kw@WoACY@a@CWQWe@[QIOYMYW]SMQUQu@OWWSUWU[SsAEg@Ic@Mc@?a@Ai@Em@AUOa@M_@e@g@MSGYOY_@YIQSR[Pa@mBQaAI[@QDyACq@Iu@o@k@e@Y]IcAAmBC]Ee@IgAUWAw@Ae@GWSaAeAYk@Si@a@k@YAc@O{@]a@MnAqA~@mCVaAHk@YmCIQSQOS')
>>> l[:5]
[(19.52691, 73.17778), (19.52664, 73.1779), (19.52663, 73.17786), (19.52662, 73.17784), (19.5265, 73.1779)]
>>> len(l)
293
```

As you can see, it has 293 points. Next I tried [this](https://open-polyline-decoder.60devs.com/) utility:

[image]

When I copy pasted that latlong array in jsoneditor, I realized that it resulted in set of 299 lat-long points.

So to find why polyline found only 293 points, I checked polyline's [github page](https://github.com/frederickjansen/polyline). I found that we cab pass precision parameter to `decode()`. But varying different values for this parameters still gave 293 points.

So now I am guessing which one is correct, online utility or polyline package?

Also is there any other official or known to be correct Python package for polyline decoding?

Comment: Check also this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924834/decoding-polyline-with-new-google-maps-api

Comment: @Taras But as I said, I want it in python and the link you shared is I guess in Java or Kotlin?

Comment: Here is a great Python implementation I use a lot myself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33557535/8947209. I can tell from my experience that the result from this implementation is correct. At least I had 0 issues in hundred of tests.

Comment: @MrXsquared thanks, can you also tell how (in which format) we can store polyline in postgres so that QGIS can correctly render it? Can you please share any link discussing the same?

Answer (score 1):

I found up your mistake.
you forgot to add r to the string s.t it won't consider special string combinations. (i.e: r"")

if you'll define the str this way, you'll have 299 points this way.